# Generate <tables> on loop

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a select that result in this data:

```
Paul    2
Paul    5
Mary    7
Jody    8
Carlos  9
Carlos  0
```

I am trying to output each group of the same **Name** in one table, like:

Table 1:

```
Paul    2
Paul    5
```

Table 2:

```
Mary    7
```

Table 3:

```
Jody    8
```

Table 4:

```
Carlos  9
Carlos  0
```

But I only know how to do it in a single table (the output will be like the select result. And the code I am using is:

```
<%
Set MasterData= TaskConnection.Execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE1")
If Not MasterData.EOF Then
%>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>AMOUNT</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <%
        While Not MasterData.EOF
        Name= MasterData("Name")
        Amount= MasterData("Amount")
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><% Response.Write Name%></td>
        <td><% Response.Write Amount%></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        MasterData.MOVENEXT
        Wend
    %>
</table>
<%
End if
%>
```

Any help in how to generate a new table on a new **Name** loop will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like the following:

```
<%
Set MasterData= TaskConnection.Execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE1")
If Not MasterData.EOF Then
%>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>AMOUNT</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<%  prevName = ""
    While Not MasterData.EOF
        Name= MasterData("Name")
        Amount= MasterData("Amount")
        if prevName <> Name and prevName <> "" then
%>
          </table>
          <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>NAME</th>
                   <th>AMOUNT</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
<%      end if
        prevName = Name
%>
    <tr>
        <td><% Response.Write Name%></td>
        <td><% Response.Write Amount%></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        masterData.MOVENEXT
    Wend
%>
</table>
<%
End if
%>
```

Comment: happy to help :)